# Неверный ответ c++

Tags: c++, math

При решении выводится не тот результат, подскажите пожалуйста,что не так. 
[image: Задание]

```
double x,y,z,s,d;
cout << "Vvedite x: ";
cin >> x;
cout << "Vvedite y: ";
cin >> y;
cout << "Vvedite z: ";
cin >> z;
d = fabs(y - x);
s = (pow(x, y + 1) + exp(y - 1)) / (1 + x* fabs(y - tan(z)));
s *=(1 + fabs(y - x) + ((pow(d, 2) / 2) - (pow(d, 3) / 3))); 
cout << "Result s= "<< s << endl;
```

Comment: "не тот результат" - никогда не говорите - какой

Comment: `s *=(1 + fabs(y - x) + ((pow(d, 2) / 2) - (pow(d, 3) / 3)));` - Вы еще не освоили короткую запись - не используйте ее

Comment: У вас "невнимательность", часть выражения пропущена. А именно два последних слагаемых. И проверьте приоритеты скобками везде. Лучше записать это одним выражением.

Comment: Я понял куда хвост (слагаемые) дели, вы его не туда поставили, в умножение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Должно быть не

```
s *=(1 + fabs(y - x) + ((pow(d, 2) / 2) - (pow(d, 3) / 3)));
```

а, например,

```
s = s*(1 + fabs(y - x)) + ((pow(d, 2) / 2) - (pow(d, 3) / 3)));
```